How Can remove AllDay section and current day?
"I’m using syncfusion_flutter_calendar and want to remove the All Day section and current-day. How can I achieve this? I’d appreciate any guidance or code examples. Thanks!"
I have highlighted the part I want to remove in red.

"I’m using syncfusion_flutter_calendar and want to remove the All Day section and current-day. How can I achieve this? I’d appreciate any guidance or code examples. Thanks!"
